# Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected when appending the Id dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mean-stack, string-interpolation

I have a filter in html, for which if I wrote the following condition to apply the ID

```
<my-filter [myDynamicId] = "isShowWaterMark ? 'showWaterMarkFilter' : water{{valueList?.code}}"></my-filter>
```

But when I run the code , I am getting the following error

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 42 in [isShowWaterMark ? 'showWaterMarkFilter' : water{{valueList?.code}}]
```

Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Maybe post more of your code?

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `''` around the second part and you shouldn't use interpolating within square brackets variable assignments.

this should fix it:

```
<my-filter [myDynamicId] = "isShowWaterMark ? 'showWaterMarkFilter' : 'water' + valueList?.code"></my-filter>
```

the error reported, is because the interpollation `{{ ... }}` cannot be used withing the square bracket variable assignment `[myDynamicId] ="<here>"`